# Using getpeername with descriptor as 0

Tags: c++, sockets

I got an old code with this line:

```
getpeername(0, (struct sockaddr *)&sin, &namelen)
```

What does the `getpeername(0,...)` does?
It works with all the OS?
I tried to compile and run in the SUN and i get this => Socket operation on non-socket
I did some research on the internet but i did't understood why i use this line, it returns my "localhost" ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks for the peer, that is, the host on the other side of the network, of file descriptor 0, which is STDIN.

It is probably a simple way of checking whether the standard input has been redirected to a socket. which is usual in *inetd* style daemons: If it returns an error then it was started as a normal daemon, but if it success, then it is started as a *inetd* daemon, and this very socket is the one to be used for the daemon operation.

Comment: Sorry for the question, but how i start a inetd style daemons

Comment: @demonofnight: Well, to start it in inetd mode, you don't start it manually, it is started by the [inetd](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inetd) daemon. Or, more recently, by systemd, IIRC.

Answer (score 0):

Try `man getpeername`. This is a POSIX API, so should be supported on UNIX and Linux platforms.

The first argument must be the fd of a conneted socket. It will fill in the address of the peer (the other side). Details of how to use the length argument: see man-page

Your call will work only, if fd 0 (stdin) is bound to a socket.

That is typically the case for servers started by inetd, but you don't tell us about the context.

You may want to change tags: this is a UNIX socket question, but has no particular relationship to C++.

Comment: It's also supported on Windows: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738533(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You're getting that error because file descriptor `0` is usually the standard input, not a socket.  I'm not sure what the original author intended, but it shouldn't work the way it is.  Maybe with some more context I can help you further.